# Calculating the proper power of a motor

Tags: design, motors, power, equipment-selection

I'm trying to build a filament extruder with some basic available tools and materials. Simply the main principle of the machine is to insert some amount of plastic raw material ( ABS in our Case ) to a hopper , move them inside a barrel with the help of helical screw which is derived by a motor, heating the material and extruding it from a predefined hole size.

lets assume that these are our givens:

1. Tube inner diameter: 20 mm
2. Helical screw outer diameter: 18 mm
3. Helical screw body diameter: 15 mm
4. Helical screw pitch: 30 mm
5. ABS density @ melting: 0.97 gr/cc
6. Motor speed: 30 RPM
7. Material output hole: 3 mm

Now what is the proper power of the motor to drive the machine?

Comment: That’s highly dependable of your material’s viscosity at cartain given temperature.

Comment: @PDuarte is there a driving equation for such a relation ?

Comment: There should be an aproximation equation in fluid mechanics given that your opening is a simple geometric hole. But that’s not the worst part. I doubt you’ll find any analytical solution to model your helical screw. Best approach is to run a CFD model.